# Loop through object array until lat/lng is not zero

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an object array with marker lat/lngs and sometimes the addresses aren't geocoded so I would like to skip lat: 0, lng: 0.
What I'm trying to accomplish now is setting up a loop so that it loops through the array and finds the first object that isn't null.

It won't show the map, saying it is undefined.

This is what I've come up with so far.

```
var Points = [{
    lat: 0,
    lng: 0
}, {
    lat: 42,
    lng: -72
}, {
    lat: 41,
    lng: -73
}];

function initMap()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Points.length; i++)
    {
        if (Points[i].lat * Points[i].lng != 0)
        {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(Points[i].lat, Points[i].lng),
                zoom: 10,
                scaleControl: true
            })
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's strange, but regardless I would like to figure out a way to get it to skip 0, 0

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy I tried your code and it is running well so I don't know what undefined error you are encountering.

Comment: you can use array.filter method if you want to test array entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array.filter`:

```js
var Points = [{
    lat: 0,
    lng: 0
}, {
    lat: 42,
    lng: -72
}, {
    lat: 41,
    lng: -73
}];

/**
 Given an object with `lat` and `lng` properties, return true if both `lat` and `lng` !== 0
 
 - parameter p: the Point to test
 
 - return: Bool true if both `lat` and `lng` !== 0
 */
function pointIsNonZero(p) {
  return p.lat !== 0 && p.lng !== 0;
}

console.log(Points.filter(pointIsNonZero));
```